# How to seperate two json files by string?

Tags: json, python-3.x, split

I am trying to parse a JSON from a website in order to extract some data. Somehow the JSON is "combined", meaning that the dataset for one product is described and without separating the next, the JSON simply continues. This throws an error in `json.load` (python3.8).

Here is the part in question:

```
"name": "30 stk"
                  }
              }
                      }                                               {
            "@type":"Product"
```

`jsonlint` outputs the following error:

```
Error: Parse error on line 126:
...30 stk"          }       }   } {     "@type": "Produc
--------------------^
Expecting 'EOF', '}', ',', ']', got '{'
```

Full JSON:

```
{"@context":"https://schema.org","@type":"Product","@id":"/antistax-extra-venentabletten-bei-venenleiden-60stk-pzn-00002335","aggregateRating":{"@type":"AggregateRating","ratingValue":"4,8","reviewCount":"26"},"description":"AntistaxextraVenentablettenbeiVenenleiden60stkkaufenbeiderOnlineApothekeapo-discounter.Medikamente,Nahrungsergänzungenuvm.erhaltenSieinunsererVersandapothekezugünstigenPreisen.","name":"AntistaxextraVenentablettenbeiVenenleiden(60stk)","image":"https://www.apodiscounter.de/images/product_images/info_images/00002335_4.jpg","sku":"00002335","mpn":"00002335","productID":"00002335","category":"Venenerkrankung","brand":{"@type":"Organization","name":"Antistax"},"offers":{"@type":"Offer","availability":"https://schema.org/InStock","url":"https://www.apodiscounter.de/antistax-extra-venentabletten-bei-venenleiden-60stk-pzn-00002335","price":"27.49","priceValidUntil":"2021-01-26","priceCurrency":"EUR","category":"Filmtabletten","eligibleQuantity":"60stk","itemCondition":"NewCondition","seller":{"@type":"Organization","name":"apo-discounter.de"}},"issimilarto":[{"@type":"Product","mpn":"00002312","name":"AntistaxextraVenentablettenbeiVenenleiden","url":"https://www.apodiscounter.de/antistax-extra-venentabletten-bei-venenleiden-30stk-pzn-00002312","description":"AntistaxextraVenentablettenbeiVenenleiden30stkkaufenbeiderOnlineApothekeapo-discounter.Medikamente,Nahrungsergänzungenuvm.erhaltenSieinunsererVersandapothekezugünstigenPreisen.","image":"https://www.apodiscounter.de/images/product_images/info_images/00002312.jpg","sku":"00002312","brand":{"@type":"Organization","name":"Antistax"},"aggregateRating":{"@type":"AggregateRating","ratingValue":"5,0","reviewCount":"13"},"review":[{"@type":"Review","author":"ErnaD.","datePublished":"30.10.2020","description":"","name":"","reviewRating":{"@type":"Rating","bestRating":"5","ratingValue":"5","worstRating":"1"}},{"@type":"Review","author":"DomenicaZ.","datePublished":"04.09.2020","description":"","name":"","reviewRating":{"@type":"Rating","bestRating":"5","ratingValue":"5","worstRating":"1"}},{"@type":"Review","author":"RitaS.","datePublished":"11.07.2020","description":"kaumwirksam","name":"","reviewRating":{"@type":"Rating","bestRating":"5","ratingValue":"5","worstRating":"1"}},{"@type":"Review","author":"VerifizierterKunde","datePublished":"10.04.2020","description":"Binnichtganzüberzeugt","name":"","reviewRating":{"@type":"Rating","bestRating":"5","ratingValue":"5","worstRating":"1"}},{"@type":"Review","author":"VerifizierterKunde","datePublished":"06.03.2020","description":"BinpositivüberraschtvondemProdukt","name":"","reviewRating":{"@type":"Rating","bestRating":"5","ratingValue":"5","worstRating":"1"}}],"offers":{"@type":"Offer","availability":"https://schema.org/InStock","url":"https://www.apodiscounter.de/antistax-extra-venentabletten-bei-venenleiden-30stk-pzn-00002312","price":"15.99","priceValidUntil":"2021-01-26","priceCurrency":"EUR","eligibleQuantity":{"@type":"QuantitativeValue","name":"30stk"}}}{"@type":"Product","mpn":"05954715","name":"AntistaxextraVenentablettenbeiVenenschwäche","url":"https://www.apodiscounter.de/antistax-extra-venentabletten-bei-venenschwaeche-90stk-pzn-05954715","description":"AntistaxextraVenentablettenbeiVenenschwäche90stkkaufenbeiderOnlineApothekeapo-discounter.Medikamente,Nahrungsergänzungenuvm.erhaltenSieinunsererVersandapothekezugünstigenPreisen.","image":"https://www.apodiscounter.de/images/product_images/info_images/05954715.jpg","sku":"05954715","brand":{"@type":"Organization","name":"Antistax"},"aggregateRating":{"@type":"AggregateRating","ratingValue":"4,8","reviewCount":"167"},"review":[{"@type":"Review","author":"VerifizierterKunde","datePublished":"05.12.2020","description":"","name":"","reviewRating":{"@type":"Rating","bestRating":"5","ratingValue":"5","worstRating":"1"}},{"@type":"Review","author":"RoswithaT.","datePublished":"23.11.2020","description":"","name":"","reviewRating":{"@type":"Rating","bestRating":"5","ratingValue":"5","worstRating":"1"}},{"@type":"Review","author":"RalfZ.","datePublished":"22.11.2020","description":"Gutundpreiswert!","name":"","reviewRating":{"@type":"Rating","bestRating":"5","ratingValue":"5","worstRating":"1"}},{"@type":"Review","author":"ReinhardS.","datePublished":"22.11.2020","description":"","name":"","reviewRating":{"@type":"Rating","bestRating":"5","ratingValue":"5","worstRating":"1"}},{"@type":"Review","author":"VerifizierterKunde","datePublished":"08.11.2020","description":"WennmanProblememitVenenhatundlangeaufdenBeinenist,hilftesdenTagbesserzumeistern...","name":"","reviewRating":{"@type":"Rating","bestRating":"5","ratingValue":"5","worstRating":"1"}}],"offers":{"@type":"Offer","availability":"https://schema.org/InStock","url":"https://www.apodiscounter.de/antistax-extra-venentabletten-bei-venenschwaeche-90stk-pzn-05954715","price":"33.49","priceValidUntil":"2021-01-26","priceCurrency":"EUR","eligibleQuantity":{"@type":"QuantitativeValue","name":"90stk"}}},{"@type":"Product","mpn":"16156023","name":"AntistaxextraVenentablettenbeiVenenleiden&Venenschwäche","url":"https://www.apodiscounter.de/antistax-extra-venentabletten-bei-venenleiden-venenschwaeche-180stk-pzn-16156023","description":"AntistaxextraVenentablettenbeiVenenleiden&amp;Venenschwäche180stkkaufenbeiderOnlineApothekeapo-discounter.Medikamente,Nahrungsergänzungenuvm.erhaltenSieinunsererVersandapothekezugünstigenPreisen.","image":"https://www.apodiscounter.de/images/product_images/info_images/16156023.jpg","sku":"16156023","aggregateRating":{"@type":"AggregateRating","ratingValue":"5,0","reviewCount":"3"},"review":[{"@type":"Review","author":"IrinaL.","datePublished":"20.01.2021","description":"","name":"","reviewRating":{"@type":"Rating","bestRating":"5","ratingValue":"5","worstRating":"1"}},{"@type":"Review","author":"AlfredS.","datePublished":"20.01.2021","description":"","name":"","reviewRating":{"@type":"Rating","bestRating":"5","ratingValue":"5","worstRating":"1"}},{"@type":"Review","author":"VerifizierterKunde","datePublished":"11.01.2021","description":"","name":"","reviewRating":{"@type":"Rating","bestRating":"5","ratingValue":"5","worstRating":"1"}}],"offers":{"@type":"Offer","availability":"https://schema.org/InStock","url":"https://www.apodiscounter.de/antistax-extra-venentabletten-bei-venenleiden-venenschwaeche-180stk-pzn-16156023","price":"56.49","priceValidUntil":"2021-01-26","priceCurrency":"EUR","eligibleQuantity":{"@type":"QuantitativeValue","name":"180stk"}}}],"review":[{"@type":"Review","author":"KlausS.","datePublished":"11.12.2020","description":"","name":"","reviewRating":{"@type":"Rating","bestRating":"5","ratingValue":"4","worstRating":"1"}},{"@type":"Review","author":"OttiZ.","datePublished":"19.10.2020","description":"Zufrieden","name":"","reviewRating":{"@type":"Rating","bestRating":"5","ratingValue":"5","worstRating":"1"}},{"@type":"Review","author":"MonikaM.","datePublished":"03.09.2020","description":"","name":"","reviewRating":{"@type":"Rating","bestRating":"5","ratingValue":"5","worstRating":"1"}},{"@type":"Review","author":"RitaP.","datePublished":"14.08.2020","description":"","name":"","reviewRating":{"@type":"Rating","bestRating":"5","ratingValue":"5","worstRating":"1"}},{"@type":"Review","author":"VerifizierterKunde","datePublished":"24.07.2020","description":"","name":"","reviewRating":{"@type":"Rating","bestRating":"5","ratingValue":"3","worstRating":"1"}}]}
```

How can I separate those two or is there a function for this? I tried `.split('} {')` but this did not work.

Comment: Please [edit] your question and provide a [mre] and sample JSON input.

Comment: I added the full JSON string

Comment: @merlin Maybe you just want to replace `} {` with `}, {`?

Comment: YES!! Thank you! I was missing a space at a first try and went another route thereafter. Great, it works now.

Comment: @merlin Ok, I've updated my answer ;-)

Answer (score 0):

It seems you have a JSON array containing two JSON objects not separated by a comma.

You should just replace `} {` with `}, {`.

Comment: This looks like a good approach, somehow there seems to be a different problem. I added full JSON to the question.